# Facebook Application Tab -> External Linking with PHP

Tags: php, facebook

I currently have an Application on the Facebook Tab, and am wondering if there is a way for me to deep link into an item on that app tab.  Example:

User is in the application (which is searching books), finds a book they like, and wants to share it with a friend.  They click to share it, and I can pull all the info, however I don't have a deep link so when it's emailed, facebooked, ect.. it sends the user directly to the page with it on it.

Is this possible on the Application Tab? I know on the canvas I could deep link fine... but looking for a way to do it on the App Tab.

Thank you for your thought and responses.

Comment: NOTE: Facebook is constantly re-inventing how they do everything.. Thank you very much to gerard for posting the latest answer on how this works.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Here's how we deep link to subpages *within* our app's Page Tab.

When your application lives inside a Page Tab, Facebook will strip out all GET params except for `app_data`. It passes `app_data` inside the `signed_request` parameter of the POST data.

More info in the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/

So when we build links to subpages, it will look something like

```
http://www.facebook.com/myfanpage?sk=app_XXXXXX&app_data=%2Fmainpage%2Fsubpage
```

Then, in our index page code, we check for the `app_data` param. If it exists, then a simple 302 redirect does the trick.

```
$request = parse_signed_request($_POST['signed_request']);
if ($request['app_data'])
{
    header('HTTP/1.1 302 Found');
    header('Location: {$request['app_data']}');
    exit;
}
```

Note: you can pass more than 1 param inside of `app_data` using a URL-encoded, JSON-array or something like that.

Comment: Thank you for making an answer on this old question; as facebook constantly re-invents how they are doing things; it's nice to have an updated response with the current best method of working through it.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps.

For Application Canvas Pages, Facebook forwards any addition URI information to your canvas callback.

For example, if your app page is `http://apps.facebook.com/testapp`

and your canvas callback is `http://facebook.example.com/testapp/canvas`

Then going to `http://apps.facebook.com/testapp/foo?bar=baz` would result in facebook's servers hitting yours like so `http://facebook.example.com/testapp/canvas/foo?bar=baz`.

I've never tested it to see if application tabs share this behavior, but it's worth a shot.  If so, you could just use URI information to drive your deeplinking.

Also, you should be aware of the [impending changes](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/402) to application tabs.

Comment: I've never been more frustrated developing with a 'major platform' before.. it seems like it's changed gears 9 times since i've started.  How can facebook be so large, yet so incredible stupid in developing APIs..

Thank you for your comment, I will give it a test and let you know. Cheers!

Comment: This didn't work :/ Thank you for the answer though, as it lead me to seeing how I can at least link to the app tab.  Still struggling to find how to deep link in with a parameter.

Answer (score 2):

For those that need a full (yet minimal working) example (like myself) here is the index.php which does the deep-linking when needed. Make sure you've downloaded the [Facebook PHP SDK](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/) and that your `require` path points to it. (Obviously, you also need to replace the `$app_id` and `$app_secret` with your own app info.)

```
<?php
require 'facebook-php-sdk/src/facebook.php';

$app_id     = "YOUR_APP_ID_HERE";
$app_secret = "YOUR_APP_SECRET_ID_HERE";

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => $app_id,
    'secret' => $app_secret
));

$signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();

// Get app_data from signed request POST
$app_data = $signed_request["app_data"];

// Parse app_data & Re-direct
if ($app_data) {
    header("HTTP/1.1 302 Found");
    header("Location: {$app_data}");
exit;
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Title Here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Landing Page</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Also, make sure that within your FB App Settings, all your URL paths (i.e. Canvas URL, Page Tab URL, etc) end with a backslash, or else you'll get some 301 redirect errors.

Once your app is setup and you've [added it your fan page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/add_to_page/), you can deep link with something like:

```
http://www.facebook.com/pages/MYFANPAGE/XXXXX?sk=app_XXXXX&app_data=sub/another.php
```

You may have to parse the actual app_data value before using it, but for me it worked just as above.

Hope that helps others out there. Of course, Facebook may change all this at any time.

Answer (score 1):

So far, we have not been able to deep link to an application Tab using URL parameters.

We are able to retrieve window.location information from an application page (e.g. `http://apps.facebook.com/testapp/foo?bar=bar`)

This does **not** work on an app Tab (e.g. `http://www.facebook.com/testpage?v=app_1234&bar=bar`)

Similarly, we cannot use `$_GET['foo']` to try to grab it server-side if we are in a Facebook tab.

If anyone has managed to get around this, I'd love to know the solution.

Comment: See above - you must use the 'app_data' parameter provided by Facebook.