# Passing php variables to Facebook Application Tab

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Are you able to send php variables to a application in a tab (in facebook)?

I have built a system which sends a wall post to a friend, which includes a link with a php variable in it. This variable needs to be processed by the app, but I cant work out how to (or if I can) do this.

Comment: Please give code or be more explicit. Facebook doesn't know that your script is PHP, it just wait for html/fbml code, then I don't understand what you try to do as "passing php variables to application". Did you var_dump ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, you can pass URL Parameters to an iFrame Tab App.

Pass the parameter: http://www.facebook.com/MyPage?sk=MyApp&app_data=any_string_here

Receive the parameter: $app_data = $signed_request["app_data"];

See more:
http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=92661

Comment: This answer should be accepted as correct, not the answer by @Ciaran

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a duplicate of the following question:

[Facebook Application Tab -> External Linking with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3524501/facebook-application-tab-external-linking-with-php)

It does not seem to be possible to pass URL parameters into a Facebook application that is in a Tab.  You can do it on the Application page however.

---

Edit: as per the answer below, this behaviour has changed. Details here: http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=92661